# NiFi - JMS acknowledgement after processing

Tags: queue, jms, apache-nifi

Is it possible to acknowledge a message from JMS using NiFi after processing it?

More specifically, I want to use ConsumeJMS processor to read a message from a queue, process it (using multiple NiFi processors), send it into Kafka using PublishKafka processor and only then send an acknowledgement to JMS. In other words, I do not want to remove the message from the queue before it is committed into Kafka.

I know that there are multiple acknowledgement modes, however none of them seems to do what I need. I aim to achieve similar effect as with HandleHttpRequest and HandleHttpResponse processors, when I am able to send a response after the message is processed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases like JMS and Kafka, the nifi processor that retrieves the data will write it to NiFi's internal repositories, commit to the internal repositories, and then send the acknowledgement to the source system. So it sends the ack in the source processor after it is guaranteed to be in NiFi.

There is an effort called NiFi stateless which is more geared to what you described where it can run a linear series of processors and perform any commit/ack until the very end. This effort is fairly new and under development.

Comment: Thank you. I am thinking about creating two custom processor. The first one would read a message from JMS without sending an acknowledgment and then it would wait (i.e. it would not read new messages). The second one would be at the end of the processing (e.g. after NiFi would receive acknowledgment from Kafka), it would send acknowledgment to JMS and finally it would notify the first custom processor via custom controller service (so it can start reading new messages again). Do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: It might be possible, but seems like it would be very limited in terms of performance since source processor can't continue consuming until downstream processors complete. Once the data is in nifi you should be able to guarantee delivery to Kafka without doing this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am aware of the inefficiency. The problem I am trying to solve is that I have a fail-over NiFi cluster (i.e. only one node is processing the data at any moment). If I understand NiFi correctly, even though a message is committed to NiFi, it is only stored on a single node within the cluster, and thus if it fails, the message will be lost (or delayed).

Comment: That is correct. Depending on your environment there should be ways of ensuring the data is not lost, and is just delayed until you bring NiFi back up on that node. i.e. in a containerized environment launching a new container and pointing at the same persistent volumes from the crashed container, or in more traditional environment using standard RAID configuration of disks