# ConsumeJMS AcknowledgeMode in Stateless Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am reading, [NiFi - JMS acknowledgement after processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63357455/nifi-jms-acknowledgement-after-processing), and got answer to use nifi stateless (or ExecuteStateless on v1.16) to not remove message from Queue until all process in Data Flow result are ok.

But i am not clear if there is impact for different Acknowledgement Mode on removing message from Queue,

1. Auto Acknowledge
2. Client Acknowledge
3. Dups OK Acknowledge

Are they all behave the same when running on nifi stateless (or ExecuteStateless on v1.16), i.e. only remove message from Queue upon successful execution of all process in Data Flow?

I havent tried anything to check for the behavior.